# Search form, if no value go to site

Tags: html, search, redirect

I have a search form which searchers wikipedia.com. Nothing fancy, a form with an input.

If the input is empty, currently the user is redirected here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&redirs=1&search=&fulltext=Search&ns0=1 .

Id like to redirect the users here: www.wikipedia.com instead

How can I do this?

This is my search form:

```
<form method="get" action="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="Special:Search" name="title"/>        
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="redirs"/>
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="hidden" value="Search" name="fulltext"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="ns0"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to send them to `en.wikipedia.org`, or did you need it to the `.com` TLD for a reason?

Comment: @DavidThomas I do need the tld for a reason. I don't mind using jQuery? But I was thinking if its possible with no JS. Either will be using on submit if value = "" window.location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, I don't think, without using JavaScript; if, as you've indicated, you're willing to use jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(
    function(){
        if ($(this).find('input:text').val() == ''){
            $(this).attr('action','http://www.wikipedia.com/');
        }
        else {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jWdWF/1/).

In plain JavaScript, the following seems to work (tested in Chromium 12 and Firefox 7 on Ubuntu 11.04):

```
var formEl = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var inputs = formEl.getElementsByTagName('input');
var textInputEl = [];
for(i in inputs){
    if (inputs[i].type == 'text'){
        textInputEl.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}

formEl.onsubmit = function(){
    if (textInputEl.value === '' || textInputEl.value === null){
        this.action = 'http://www.wikipedia.com/';
    }
    else {
        formEl.submit;
    }
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jWdWF/2/).

---

I'm trying to set this up so that, with an empty text-input, the form will remove any `hidden` elements and then set the `action`, or the `document.location` to be `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random`. This does not, for some reason, seem to work. Almost as if Wikipedia's finding something wrong and then redirecting to a different page. Ungh. Anyways, this is what I *tried*:

```
 $('form').submit(
    function(){
        if ($(this).find('input:text').val() == ''){
            $(this).find('input:hidden').remove();
            $(this).attr('action','http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random');
        }
        else {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jWdWF/4/);

```
 $('form').submit(
    function(){
        if ($(this).find('input:text').val() == ''){
            $(this).find('input:hidden').remove();
            document.location.href = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random';
            /*
                I also tried 'document.location','window.location' 
                and 'window.location.href' all of which, predictably,
                failed in exactly the same way.
            */
        }
        else {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jWdWF/5/);

Comment: thank you. It's kinda this is what I was looking for but you know the form has few hidden input's which are applied to the URL on submit. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jWdWF/1/show/ . Basically can I disable those? Because actually I id like to redirect here on empty field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random . The idea of this is that when the field is empty, to search something random. Thanks alot again

Comment: So, if the text-input is empty you want to disable the values from the hidden inputs, and then send the visitor to the `Special:Random` page?

Comment: Exactly, thats what I want to do. By the way, I am using jQuery

Comment: Thank you. I used your 3rd solution but I had to add this: $(this).find('input:text').attr('name',''); otherwise it was adding a "?search" at the end making it not to work. Thanks alot sir

Comment: Oooh, good call! You're quite welcome; I'm glad to have been of help and thank *you* for the accept! =)